# Getting Error 'type parameters cannot be used as qualifiers'

Tags: vb.net, generics

I am getting this error with the following code. I must be missing something. This is pretty basic stuff.

```
Public Function GetSingleValue() As T
    If Items.Count = 0 Then Throw New Exception(T.CommonName & " can not be found")
    If Items.Count > 1 Then Throw New Exception("There are mulitple " & T.CommonName & " items found")
    Return Items(0)
End Function
```

Items() returns a List(of T). 
CommonName is a member of the class that T represents

Why am I getting this error? Alternately, is there a construct in vb.Net that would allow me to do this.

Comment: `T` is a Type just as `String` would be if the method was `GetSingleValue() As String`.  You would not try to use `String.Length` there would you?  is that an extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also apply the `System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute` to your classes in order to assign them a common name.

```
<DisplayName("Super Class")> _
Public Class MyClass
End Class
```

Place this function in a module

```
Public Function GetDisplayName(type As Type) As String
    Dim attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(DisplayNameAttribute), False)

    If attributes.Length = 0 Then
        Return type.Name 'No DisplayNameAttribute, so use class name instead
    End If
    Return DirectCast(attributes(0), DisplayNameAttribute).DisplayName
End Function
```

And use it like this

```
Public Function GetSingleValue() As T
    Dim commonName As String = GetDisplayName(GetType(T))
    If items.Count = 0 Then Throw New Exception($"{commonName} not found")
    If items.Count > 1 Then Throw New Exception($"Multiple {commonName} items found")
    Return items(0)
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

- If you know the class that T represents, there's no need to use generics here.
- If you don't know the class that T represents, there's nothing stopping your users from supplying a class which does *not* have a CommonName shared property. Thus, the compiler cannot *ensure* that the CommonName property exists, and, thus, won't allow you do that. Note that requiring a common base class won't help, since [shared (static in C#) properties are not inherited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3578421/87698).

Comment: there are ~30 classes that use this generic. I am trying to provide functionality that is common to all of them.

Comment: @greg: I understand that. Unfortunately, there is no generic type constraint that checks for the existence of a property. My suggestion for an alternative solution would be a shared `CommonNameDictionary As Dictionary(Of Type, String)` or Oliver's attribute solution. Reflection would also be an option, but that's not very elegant.

Comment: A dictionary is a possibility on par w/ my current approach.  the detraction there is that the inelegant supporting code is in a different location. My declaring an instance is clearly inelegant, but at least its right there where it can be commented upon.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Function GetSingleValue() As T
    Dim x as new T
    If Items.Count = 0 Then Throw New Exception(x.CommonName & " can not be found")
    If Items.Count > 1 Then Throw New Exception("There are multiple " & x.CommonName & " items found")
    Return Items(0)
End Function
```

Plutonix pointed out my mistake. 
CommonName is not a Shared Property so you need an instance. 
I would like CommonName to be shared somehow, but that's a different question.
I also misspelled multiple.

Comment: while not very elegant, this does resolve the problem.  My root challenge is that i am struggling to find a way to implement a shared property on a constructed type.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you need instead of generics is an interface that your "~30 classes" will implement:

```
Public Interface Example
    Property CommonName As String
    ... other methods or properties
End Interface
```

Then in your code 'Items' returns a List(Of Example).

Comment: The advantage of generics, in this case , is that I can find a single Purchase order and have all the properties/methods of a PO, including those specific to a PO.  I can also find a single DeliveryVan, and have all the properties/methods of a DeliveryVan, including those specific to a DeliveryVan.  An interface would force me to a common subset of properties.